# Should “cum” be included in this sentence or not?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, ablative, cum

I have a sentence that I need to translate:

> *Having left the forum with haste, ...* etc

And I'm translating it as "*e foro cum celeritate egressi, ...*" (the rest of the sentence refers to multiple people hence why I'm using *egressi*) but I'm not sure whether I need to include *cum* in this sentence.

Does it make more sense/is it a better practice to not include *cum*, just leaving *celeritate* in the ablative on its own, so it reads *e foro celeritate egressi* or am I just being needlessly doubtful?

Comment: Here I am going off at a tangent, again: Are you sort-of remembering *'quam celerrime'* "as quickly as possible" ?

Comment: Greetings to the fellow travelers from HNQ expecting something a little more spicy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case, *celeritate* should be used with *cum*.

The general rule for the **ablative of manner** is that it should be used with *cum* if the ablative isn't modified by an adjective. [Dale A. Grote](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=dwup0fNGcG8C&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=%22celeritate%22%20without%20cum&source=bl&ots=4GzfHDquha&sig=ACfU3U2hSAfy9pgPu3c4WRwjoXYWc8H1nw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBhK2n663yAhXLpZUCHdJWDFwQ6AF6BAgQEAM#v=onepage&q=%22celeritate%22%20without%20cum&f=false) explains this rule:

> When the noun in this kind of construction is modified by an
> adjective, Latin has the option of dropping the preposition **cum**. This
> sentence could also be written: **Id magna celeritate fecerunt**. But
> if the noun governed by **cum** is not qualified by an adjective, the
> **cum** *must* be used. This is incorrect: **Id celeritate fecerunt**; but this is correct: **Id cum celeritate fecit**. And so is this: **Id
> magna cum celeritate fecit**; this is fine, too: **Id magni celeritate
> fecit**.

However, as is often the case, there are exceptions to the rule (but none that affect *celeritate*). According to *[Bradley's Arnold Latin Prose Composition](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=v2JmZCV-WtoC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=%22With%20a%20number%20of%20common%20phrases%20cum%20is%20never%20used%22&source=bl&ots=zoHD9EKQFK&sig=ACfU3U2m73as0aEijNFhZPoAEhTgRsMy5w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEid2a9K3yAhW2ppUCHSp7BY8Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22With%20a%20number%20of%20common%20phrases%20cum%20is%20never%20used%22&f=false)*, the use of *cum* is optional (even without an adjective) with the following:

> *casu* "by chance" *consilio* "by design" *consulto* "deliberately"
> *forte* "by chance" *fraude* "deceitfully" *iure* "rightly"
> *iniuria* "unjustly" *silentio* "in silence" *vi* "by force"

There are also some common phrases with which *cum* is never used:

> *hoc consilio* "with this intention"
> *hoc modo, hac ratione* "in this way"
> *summo opere* "ernestly, energetically"
> *aequo animo* "calmly"
> *iussu tuo* "at your command"
> *iniussu Caesaris* "without Caesar's permission"
> *bona tua venia* "with your kind permission"
> *nullo negotio* "without trouble"
> *nescio quo pacto* "in some way or other"

Answer (score 7):

In concurrence with Expedito Bipes's answer, *cum* should be used in this sentence. Allen and Greenough's Latin Grammar states:

> The manner of an action is denoted by the ablative; usually with cum, unless a limiting adjective is used with the noun.

It lists two examples, both of which conveniently use the noun in question:

1. Cum celeritate venit. He came with speed.
2. Summa celeritate venit. He came with the greatest speed.

Since there is not adjective modifying *celeritas* in your case, *cum* is to be used.